# Can I use substr() as the needle in in_array()?

Tags: php

```
$haystack = 'I am a haystack. Hear me rawr.';
$pos = strlen($haystack);
$nlen = 1;

$needle = array('.', '. ');

print_r(in_array(substr($haystack, $pos, $nlen), $needle, true));
```

I am having trouble figuring out why this is failing. I am trying to see if an array of needles matches the result that substr chooses from the haystack? How can I return that value as boolean?

Comment: According to docs, in_array searches a string/needle in an array/haystack.
You are trying a needle/array which looks wrong to me. Parameter order is conceptually wrong.

Comment: You can have an array as needle and string as the haystack just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***Yes & NO*** because [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) returns a ***string*** which is needle in your case and ***FALSE*** on failure in which case it won't be a valid argument to `in_array` function.

You should first extract a part of string using `substr` and need to make sure that you extracted some string and it did not return `FALSE`, only then you should use it in `in_array`.